# Can't build project on iOS Error code 70, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, vue.js, vuex

Im not able to build my project (created with js, vue.js, vuex) on iOS platform. Exactly the same project works on web while typing `npm run dev` and I was able to build it on Android on laptop with Windows. When I’m trying Cordova run iOS got something like this:

`xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier: --HERE a lot of simulators-- Ineligible destinations for the "HelloCordova" scheme: { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device } { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Simulator Device } CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/username/Downloads/vue-webpack-vuetify-vuex-cordova-boilerplate-master copy/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,HelloCordova.xcworkspace,-scheme,HelloCordova,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/username/Downloads/vue-webpack-vuetify-vuex-cordova-boilerplate-master copy/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/username/Downloads/vue-webpack-vuetify-vuex-cordova-boilerplate-master copy/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch' at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

Iv also tried `cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`
but got the same error. Im using Xcode 10.1 and Cordova 8.1.2

Atm working on MacBook Pro

Answer (score 2):

`xcodebuild` error 70 means that the target for the build was not found.  It could be due to a mismatch of iOS versions, parameters, or (if using a real device) the UDID being wrong, or the device was not connected, switched off or locked.

Comment: In my case it was because my iPhone and my Macbook were not on the same wifi.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because my XCode was out-of-date and not compatible with the version of iOS on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case. I was having older versions of the iOS emulators.  then I installed the latest emulator with the latest iOS. that solves the issue..

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem with react-native, if developer mode is not enabled on the iOS device, you'll get this error 70

Answer (score 0):

In my project.pbxproj file setting value of IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET was higher then on emulator so I changed it to emulator ios version number and the problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

Issue occurs when xcode gets updated to latest and new platform version is available in xcode.

I resolved it by downloading the latest platform version

Before
17.0 was installed with xcode 15.0

After xcode auto updated to 15.1

17.2 was available, so i have resolved by installing 17.2 platform

Answer (score 0):

A simple restart for both the Mac and iPhone fixed this issue.